# Plot several recorderplot in one new plot

Tags: r, plot, graph

I would like to replay several recorded plot in one unique plot that contain all plots.
This is an example of recorded plot that I created previously.

> plot(1:10, main = "plot1")
>
> PLOT1<-recordPlot()
>
> plot(10:1, main = "plot2")
>
> PLOT2<-recordPlot()
>
> plot(rnorm(10), main = "plot3")
>
> PLOT3<-recordPlot()

Then I tried to use

> opar <- par()
>
> par(mfcol = c(1, 3))
>
> replayPlot(PLOT1)
>
> replayPlot(PLOT2)
>
> replayPlot(PLOT3)

But in these way I can only see one graph at the time and I want the three together.

Answer (score 0):

You create a list of the plots, and put them into one plot with `ggpubr::ggarrange()`.

The only tricky part is that you must also load the library `gridGraphics`, otherwise you will encounter an error.

The actual code is a one-liner:

```
library(ggpubr)
library(gridGraphics)

ggarrange(plotlist = list(PLOT1, PLOT2, PLOT3), nrow = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use gridExtra library, the code should look like this

```r
install.packages("gridExtra")
library("gridExtra")
grid.arrange(PLOT1, PLOT2, PLOT3, nrow = 1)
```

You can fit more plot into the grid, and the nrow parameter is used to determine the number of row.

Answer (score -1):

As work-around set `par(mfcol= c(1,3))` before recording as `plot` creates just `image` not object will do the trick. Actually, if `mfcol` is set as `c(1,3)` then `PLOT1` will record 'plot1' but `PLOT2` will record both 'plot1' & 'plot2' and 'PLOT3` will record all 'plot1', 'plot2' & 'plot3'. Hence, replaying those saved plots will give impression as they are shown in order.

This should work.

```
par(mfcol= c(1,3))

plot(1:10, main = "plot1")

PLOT1 <- recordPlot()

plot(10:1, main = "plot2")

PLOT2 <- recordPlot()


plot(rnorm(10), main = "plot3")

PLOT3<-recordPlot()


replayPlot(PLOT1)

replayPlot(PLOT2)

replayPlot(PLOT3)
```